# Transformation from EPSG 2178 to EPSG 4326 gml.file?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, coordinate-system, gml

How can I transform .gml file from EPSG 2178 to EPSG 4326?

I used the following without success:

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:2178 -t_srs EPSG:4326 "file1.gml"
```

Comment: did you try ogr2ogr which is known to work on vector files instead of rasters?

Answer (score 2):

As the comment suggests above, you should use `ogr2ogr` as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -f 'GML' -s_srs epsg:2178 -t_srs epsg:4326 output.gml input.gml
```

Comment: But when I do it , I see this error :                                                    Unable to find driver `'GeoJSON''.
The following drivers are available:
  -> `FileGDB'
  -> `OCI'
  -> `SOSI'
  -> `ESRI Shapefile'
  -> `MapInfo File'
  -> `UK .NTF'
  -> `SDTS'
  -> `TIGER'
  -> `S57'
  -> `DGN'

Comment: When you do `ogrinfo --formats` do you see:   -> "GML" (read/write) (or GeoJSON if that is what you need) ?

Comment: Yes I see but many others too.